# Expresso Store USPS shipping method for international orders

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

We run a store that has 50/50 Domestic & International orders daily. I am trying to set up some shipping methods using the USPS Shipping Method & can not see a way to restrict these shipping methods to international countries only.

Heres an example:

1. Create new shipping method called 'USPS International Small Flat
   Rate Box'
2. Service: Priority
3. Mail Type: Package Service
4. Container: Small Flat Rate Envelope (no small flat rate box avail)

There's a few issues with this. The biggest being no country designation so the method will apply to all countries. The 2nd being only some USPS methods are avail.

The shortcoming I believe I am finding is that the USPS module can only be used for US shipments. All international shipments will need to be created with the 'default shipping module' & using respective rules.

This certainly creates a ton more work as there's no way to set up one rule for all international countries. Basically we ship to over 50 countries. Each country would need a separate rule set up for each international shipping service. Typically this is 'USPS Priority International' , 'USPS Express International', 'USPS First-Class Package International' & 'USPS Small Flat Rate Box' - This would be 200 shipping methods needed to be created manually.

This is one area where I believe Brilliant Retail handles brilliantly with its 'Shipping Calculator'. Am I missing something or is this a huge short coming with store shipping?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/15295/150), Store currently on supports domestic (US) rates for the USPS shipping plugin.

As USPS international rates use a completely separate API, this will require some custom development if you need to get it to work worldwide.